# Search for value in element with specific attribute

Tags: xquery, marklogic

```
<elemA>
  <elemZ mytype ="1">
    <myval>100</myval>
  </elemZ>
  <elemZ mytpe ="2">
    <myval>200</myval>
  </elemZ>
</elemA>
```

Using cts:queries, I would want to find myval of 100 in elemZ **with** mytype = "1". I do not see any cts query that allows `cts:element-query` and also filtering on attribute. Even an `cts:and-query` does not appear helpful.

Without attribute constraint, element-value-query and two element-queries would work easy.

```
cts:search(doc(), (some cts query?))
```

Answer (score 3):

First try this simple xpath -- validate that it works, and that its *not* sufficiently performant for you.

```
//elemZ[@mytype=1]/myval[. = "100" ]
```

That should return myval element children of elemZ with mytype=1 and myval text content = "100"

To do better (with cts:query) will need those 'dreaded' other cts:queries and possibly some range indexes.
Roughly : (untested)

```
   search(doc(),
     cts:element-query(xs:QName("elemZ"),
       cts:and-query((
         cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("elemZ"), xs:QName("mytype"), "1"),
         cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("myval"), "100") )) ) )
```

Recommend you start with the simplest expression that does *anything* then one by one add constraints.

In your case, it's conceivable that the query optimizer will optimize the simple xpath into the appropriate cts query.  Worth trying and measuring performance.  I personally like to start with a basic xpath and then only work my way up to a cts:query as needed.